# Magento 2 - change url key programmatically

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to generate URL Keys for all products and save them using a script?

I deleted all URL keys for products from database, but now I want to generate them again using a script.

// Edit: I need to do this in Magento 2. Forgot to specify.

I got this until now:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);    
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$deploymentConfig = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$repo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
    $name = $product->getName();
    $url = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name);
    $url = strtolower($url);
    echo $url;
    $pr = $repo->getById($product->getId());
    $pr->setUrlKey($url);

    $repo->save($pr);
    break;
}
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options__() in /home2/magazi70/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Config/Source/Product/Options/Price.php on line 23

Comment: Have you solved your problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);    
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$deploymentConfig = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){

    $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
    $name = $product->getName();
    $url = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name);
    $url = strtolower($url);

    $product ->setUrlKey($url);
    $product->save($pr);

}
```

Comment: Rather than just answering with a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the problem was you solved, and how you have solved it? This will help the OP and anyone else to understand your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

The magento script may take longer time.

```
1. You can try exporting the products (the csv file will not have url keys)
2. Remove all the attributes and keep only SKU and Name and add a new attribute column url_key
3. Use some Excel Functions to generate url keys using Name
4. Remove the Name column
5. Import the csv
```

Comment: after doing this you still need to do the catalog urls regeneration right ?

Comment: may be or may not. But as per the question, the products doesn't have url keys at all.

Answer (score -1):

to loading a collection and save the new object of product is slow way to done the job

here is best way to

```
composer require elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls
php bin/magento module:enable Iazel_RegenProductUrl
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

more information are available on

https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

Comment: This will create url rewrite entries in url_rewrite table but will not update product entity url keys.

Answer (score -1):

This code shows how to generate an url key, in a helper class, the same way **Magento 2** generates url keys when creating products.
In the example I use dependency injection in order to use **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url** class in my helper.

```
namespace Myprojects\Mymodule\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context as HelperContext;


class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
    * @param Url $url
    */
    public function __construct(
                                HelperContext $context,
                                Url $url
                                )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function generateUrlKey($string)
    {
        return $this->url->formatUrlKey($string);
    }

}
```